# Developing a GUI using OpenCV and Qt C++- High-Resolution images

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, opencv

I have been chosen by my Computer Science laboratory in order to develop a Graphical User Interface (GUI) which main goal is to allow the user to open High Resolution images (TIFF format) and manipulate them (zoom in, zoom out, draw rectangles,create and edit annotations...).

I would like to build this GUI using Qt coupled with OpenCV. Nevertheless, I have some doubts about working with OpenCV for this project.

Therefore, my questions are:

- Does Qt allow you to handle High-Resolution TIFF images (2000x3000 pixels?
- Does OpenCV allow you to handle High-Resolution TIFF images?
- Is it easy to convert a OpenCV TIFF image into a Qt TIFF  image?

Comment: OpenCV is for computer vision, not for image rendering. Therefore, OpenCV will load each image completely to memory and it will typically work with 24bit BGR images. However, 2000x3000 isn't such a big size, I guess it will work. OpenCV provides simple methods to access sub-images and simple methods to resize images (with different interpolation methods). Both features you will probably need to display images that don't fit on your screen. Not sure about TIFF, but OpenCV doesn't give you access to any meta information of the loaded images.

Comment: Therefore, I guess OpenCV could be a good solution to open Tiff images. But Qt ? Can it do the same job ?

Comment: I would use a tiff library (or opencv if sufficent) for loading, openCV for resizing/subimaging and Qt for displaying + user input

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: Last thing, the qt documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html) tells us Qt uses a plugin in order to manipulate Tiff images. Does it work ? What does "bundled third-party code" mean ? Do I need to install an additional library for Qt ?

Comment: tiff images will be loaded by a tiff library or openCV and Qt will just access memory blocks with RGB values. So for Qt it doesn't matter what kind of a file has been that image in before, before all the file reading and image decoding has already been done by tiff library or OpenCV. BUT: probably that's a plugin to use TIFF images directly in Qt. If that works, you don't need OpenCV at all (if Qt allows you to zoom/subimage etc and if Qt can handle the big sized images). But if you only use Qt for displaying, you don't have to care about TIFF within Qt at all.

Comment: by today standards, 2000x3000 pixels are **not** high resolution images... your phone can probably take higher resolution still photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and edit annotations? That sounds like going much farther than process TIFF.

Supposing the original post was understood correctly in both the motivation - to create GUI capable of working with large TIFF image files which also allows users to create and ( later ) edit `annotations` and other graphical elements ( `rectangles` et al )

The solution goes in a much different way than just to how to handle TIFF images in `OpenCV` and similar tools.

If the goal is not to just reinvent wheel again, there is a lovely and powerful tool `xfig` used in CERN since ages, which provides a powerful framework for your idea.

Using `xfig`'s syntax-engine and rendering options allows you to keep objects compose-able and editable throughout the whole lifecycle of the work and leaves you more time for developing your own concept of GUI, not spending man*years of efforts on the internals of how to handle standard format pixmaps and layered vector objects on the lowest-level side.

Meta-file looks like:

```
#FIG 3.2
Landscape
Center
Inches
Letter  
200.00
Single
-3
1200 2
6 8625 825 11775 7275
6 8625 1125 9075 3975
6 8625 1125 9075 2175
6 8625 1125 9075 1575
2 1 0 3 0 7 0 0 -1 0.000 1 0 -1 0 0 2
     8700 1200 9000 1200
2 1 0 3 0 7 0 0 -1 0.000 1 0 -1 0 0 2
     8700 1500 9000 1500
-6
6 8625 1725 9075 2175
2 1 0 3 0 7 0 0 -1 0.000 1 0 -1 0 0 2
     8700 1800 9000 1800
2 1 0 3 0 7 0 0 -1 0.000 1 0 -1 0 0 2
     8700 2100 9000 2100
...
4 0 0 0 0 0 20 0.0000 4 195 1080 35100 19800 Z-80 PIO\001
4 0 0 0 0 0 15 0.0000 4 180 930 34575 21075 CTL/DAT\001
4 0 0 0 0 0 15 0.0000 4 180 795 34575 21375 B/A SEL\001
4 0 0 0 0 0 15 0.0000 4 150 270 34575 21975 A6\001
4 0 0 0 0 0 15 0.0000 4 150 270 34575 22275 A5\001
4 0 0 0 0 0 15 0.0000 4 150 480 34575 22875 GND\001
4 0 0 0 0 0 15 0.0000 4 150 270 34575 24075 A0\001
4 0 0 0 0 0 15 0.0000 4 150 600 34575 24375 A STB\001
4 0 0 0 0 0 15 0.0000 4 150 570 34575 24675 B STB\001
4 0 0 0 0 0 15 0.0000 4 150 240 36525 21975 B6\001
```

and result may look like:

[image: xfig/slxfig imagery]

[image: xfig Artwork, courtesy ** Carlo Kopp**]

Comment: But can you combine this tool with Qt ?

Comment: As the O/P defined your wish to use Qt, yes, Qt might be considered as a GUI presentation layer ( a window-manager (facility) ) while the hard work is based on xfig's composer / render services, that deliveres functionality. Anyway, Qt is based on X11 dependencies "under the hood" >>> http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/requirements-x11.html However, the Project Architecture and Solution is up to you.